# Prepend to a WCF Service output

Tags: asp.net, wcf, csrf

I'm using ASP.NET 4 WCF Services for some data transactions. To prevent CSRF (Cross-site request forgery) I'd like to prepend some data to the output. Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class TestService : ServiceBase
{
    [WebGet(
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/test.json")
    ]
    public MyResponse Test ()
    {
        MyResponse resp;
        try
        {
            Response.Write("for(;;){}"); // <-- Fix needed
            resp = new MyResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AjaxException aex = new AjaxException() { 
                message = string.Format("Test failed. Exception: {0}.", ex.Message)
            };
            throw new WebFaultException<AjaxException>(aex, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
        return resp;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyResponse {
    public MyResponse() { }
    [DataMember()]
    public long time = ServiceUtility.Convert(DateTime.Now);
    [DataMember()]
    public string secret { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to avoid using HTTP GET method on WCF operations that can change the state. To my knowledge, current browsers does not allow to do cross site POST requests with JSON content type - so this should prevent CSRF attacks.

For more security, you can check the HTTP Referrer header to see if the service calls are originated from the allowed site(s).